# Beamer with Turkish characters

Tags: beamer, characters, turkish

The code below is to create a Beamer file including Turkish letters, but the Turkish characters do not appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

şğöü

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get them. Are you sure your document is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Thats what I forgot to do. Perfectly works now

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to wrong file encoding